# Determining Start / Finish Date for Stream Sales Data (R / Tidyverse)

Tags: r, csv, dplyr, tidyr, lubridate

See [this sample file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rwe4u6gcgcemd3h/monthly_data.csv?dl=0) for my test data.

Objective: determine (**by client**) the: 1) earliest & latest dates sales were earned (and what were corresponding sales in those months); 2) what month achieved the highest sales (and what were corresponding sales)

Stuck after the tidying phase - presume this requires some use of 'summarise':

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_csv("monthly_data.csv")

tidy_df <- df %>% 
  gather(-`Client Name`, key="Year", value="Sales") %>% 
  group_by(`Client Name`) %>%
  drop_na()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just group by `Client Name` and then use `Summarise` as you expected, though my solution can likely be made more elegant.

First I would get which months that have the highest sales for each `Client Name`

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

top_months <- tidy_df %>%
 group_by(`Client Name`) %>%
 top_n(1, Sales) %>%
 mutate(top_month = month(mdy(Year))) %>%
 select(`Client Name`, top_month)
```

Then you can summarise the sale values and join the list of highest sales months back.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

tidy_df %>%
 mutate(Year = mdy(Year) %>%
 group_by(`Client Name`) %>%
 summarise(`Latest Sale` = max(Year),
        `Earliest Sale` = min(Year),
        `Highest Grossing Month Sales` = max(Sales)) %>%
 left_join(., top_months, by = "Client Name")
```

Comment: This is very close - the only thing it's missing is determining what were the sales amounts in `Latest` and `Earliest` sale.

Comment: You've given me everything I need to finish.  Thanks @plduffy !